# Why limit the length of the result of a GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

What is the reason for limiting the results of a GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL to 1024? What are the implications of raising this limit to a much higher number?

Here's an example of how to raise it:
http://blog.georgeolah.com/2013/03/mysql-group_concat-limit/

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason? Actually, ask MySQL devs. What you can do? Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743653/limit-characters-in-mysql-query-column/19743707#19743707)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to have the default value of an obscure config variable too low than too high.

The default limit seems a bit low, but it's to prevent your application's memory from being overallocated when you fetch a single row.

You can feel free to raise `group_concat_max_len` if you have the need for longer strings to be fetched from the database server.

You still shouldn't set `group_concat_max_len` higher than `max_allowed_packet`, or else the string will be truncated anyway.

The other implication of choosing a higher or lower `group_concat_max_len` value is that if the value is 255 or less, the data type of the resulting column will be CHAR or BINARY. If the max len is greater than 255, the data type will be TEXT or BLOB.